# Build MySql Query with multiple where conditions

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have to build a some complicated mysql query. I have a table with some user informations, with 3 columns: id, id_user, id_campo, valore. So, for example:

- 1, 1, 1, "Roberto" (where id_campo=1 is for the user name);
- 2, 2, 1, "Luca";
- 3, 1, 2, "Windows"; (where id_campo=2 is for used OS);
- 4, 2, 2, "Linux";
  and so on.

Now, I have to select users where: name="Roberto" AND os="Linux", but the same user :

```
SELECT id_user WHERE (id_campo=1 AND valore="Roberto") OR (id_campo=2 AND valore="Linux").
```

In this sample case, the query return id_user=1 and id_user=2 but I would obtain no result. How I can modify the query so I can include the condition "the same user" ?

Thanks!

Comment: You know that the database-construction is wrong, right? That is not how a relational database / table is supposed to work. You don't utilize mulitple relations using the same columns for different data. And why can't you just fetch the rows that match the `id_user`?

Comment: why `FROM` operator is missed?

Comment: Why is wrong? I have a users table, a "campo" table and a "user_spec" table. So an user can have different user_spec values ("Roberto", "Luca", "Windows", "Linux", ...) that is contained in "campo" ("Name", "OS", "email", ...). If it's wrong, how I can modify the db structure the best way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to build two "subqueries" and then join them by user id.

```
SELECT a.id_user
from (
    SELECT id_user FROM table
    WHERE (id_campo=1 AND valore="Roberto") 
) a, 
(
    SELECT id_user FROM table
    WHERE (id_campo=2 AND valore="Linux")
) b
WHERE a.is_user = b.id_user
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong db design  but anyway  you can usie an inner join on the same table based  on id_user

```
  select  a.id_user, a.id_campo, a.valore
  from my_table as a
  inner join my_table as b on .id_user = b-id_user
  where ( a.id_campo = 1 and a.valore ='Roberto')
  AND ( b.id_campo = 2 and b.valore ='Linux')
```